# Stateless and stateful interaction with Rule engine FROM KIE workbench

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie-wb

From the jBPM developer guide, I have understood that we can interact with the rule engine in a stateless manner (where only objects are inserted as facts) and a statefull manner (where objects and process instances are inserted as facts). My questions are

1) If you create a process model in the KIEWorkbench, containing a business rule task and you do the input and output mapping, then is this a stateless interaction with the rule engine?

2) How to interact with the rule engine from the KIEWorkbench in a stateful manner?
   I think we can use the script task to insert process instances, but how do you fire the rules?     Do we use a business rule task after the script task to fire the rules?  And then there is no need of event listeners?

Answer (score 0):

From the KIE-WB the uses of state full sessions it is a bit complicated nowadays. The first version that we have released uses stateful sessions for running business processes, but the session itself is not exposed for multi purposes. We are planning to add more tooling to interact with those sessions, but right now, unless you are willing to extend KIE WB the interaction is limited. By this I mean, there is no screen to set globals or add/retract facts to a specific session.